# SQL Server output to a file using variable name

Tags: sql-server

I want to send SQL Server output to a file which is working as expected. But if I pass the file path in a variable, It is not creating the file.

Working

```
:out 'C:\Temp.txt'
```

Not Working

```
DECLARE @BCVFileName VARCHAR(500)
SET @BCVFileName= 'C:\Temp.txt'

:out @BCVFileName
```

Could anyone please help me on this??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to store your query in Query file and then you can execute from command to store result to a text file as shown below.

```
>sqlcmd -E -S(Local)\SQLExpress -YourDBName -iC:\myQuery -oC:\Output.txt
```

Another way to use T-SQL and create a batch statement to execute via XP_CMDSHELL. Following script will help you to do the same just replace your query, ServerName with used variables.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
DECLARE @sqlcmd varchar(1000);
PRINT 'using SqlCMD.exe';
SET @sqlcmd = 'sqlcmd -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -E -oc:\outfile.txt '
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000);
SET @cmd = '-Q"SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('' '' , 6) + CONVERT(varchar, AddressID), 6 ) AS AddressID, CONVERT(varchar(10), ModifiedDate, 121) AS ModifiedDate FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address ORDER BY ModifiedDate;"';
SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + @cmd;
--SELECT @sqlcmd;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlcmd, no_output;
PRINT 'using BCP.exe';
SET @cmd = '"SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('' '' , 6) + CONVERT(varchar, AddressID), 6 ) AS AddressID, CONVERT(varchar(10), ModifiedDate, 121) AS ModifiedDate FROM AdventureWorks.Person.Address ORDER BY ModifiedDate;"';
SET @sqlcmd = 'bcp ' + @cmd + ' queryout "c:\outfile2.txt" -c -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME 
--SELECT @sqlcmd;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlcmd, no_output;
```

regards